# change colour of alternating rows in query

Tags: jquery, row, alternating

I have this table with even rows coloured grey (odd rows are white):

```
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '1'; }).text('One');
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '2'; }).text('Two');
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '3'; }).text('Three');
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '4'; }).text('Four');
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '5'; }).text('Five');
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '6'; }).text('Six');
```

I then removed row 3 like this:

```
$("tr:contains('3')").hide();
```

Now my table has rows 2 and 4 together coloured grey. How do I retain alternate row colours despite removing a row?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
function View(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;        

        $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '1'; }).text('One');
        $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '2'; }).text('Two');
        $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '3'; }).text('Three');
        $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '4'; }).text('Four');
        $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '5'; }).text('Five');
        $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '6'; }).text('Six');

            $("tr:contains('3')").hide();
            }
        }   
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "process_this_table.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();       
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="View();">
    <div id="datatable"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
body{
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 20;
  font: 2em Times New Roman, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 600px;
  box-shadow: -20px 20px 20px #313030;
}
td {
  padding: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I presume you'll tell me to add attributes for tr and would probably tell me to insert the code you provided right? If so, can you please provide the syntax. I know you can't insert jquery to css.

Tue. Jun. 4, 2013 7:50pm EST
This is the table structure inside the process_this_table.php:

```
<?php
echo "<table>"; 
    $rows=array('row 1','row 2','row 3');
    $columns=array('column 1','column 2','column 3');
    $rlength=count($rows);
    $clength=count($columns);
    for($i=0;$i<$rlength;$i++){
    echo "<tr>";        
    if($i%2){
        echo "<td style=\"background-color: rgb(212,212,212);\">".$rows[$i]."</td>";
    for($j=1;$j<$clength;$j++)
        echo "<td style=\"background-color: rgb(212,212,212);>blah blah</td>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<td>".$rows[$i]."</td>"; 
    for($j=1;$j<$clength;$j++)
        echo "<td>blah blah</td>"; 
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

This process_this_table.php is from a remote server so I can't modify the alternating grey colour (212,212,212) on even rows. For my purpose, I would prefer specifying which row I want to change colour instead of doing odd or even, like this $("tr:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "lightblue");. Why does that code not work but specifying an odd row like $("tr:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "lightblue"); does?

Wed. Jun. 5, 2013 12:50pm EST
All is well thanks to all of you, especially Karl-Andre. I'd like one more thing, though. How do I re-arrange the rows so row 4 will be on row 1 for example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i asked the HTML, i meant the HTML output, after your Javascript load content. I want to see your `<table>` and what's inside!

Comment: Hi Karl, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Just picture a table with even rows as grey and odd rows as white (no colour). I added the process_this_table.php from my original post to show how the table is built, though.

Comment: I understand PHP and that's enough to spot your problem. Making an answer!

Comment: I needed to see the DOM so i could spot any `style` attribute or how the DOM is actually made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery :`odd` selector to correctly set the colors.

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/).

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

Answer (score 1):

And what about this solution, i think you could use it for your purpose:

```
$('tr').each(function(i) {
  if (i % 2)
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  else 
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TQZfP/1/

Comment: Your solution can be reduced using [.css('propName',function(i,v)](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value) --  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/gU65U/)

Comment: It should be `$('tr:visible')`

Comment: it definitly can, thanks for pointing it out, but i imagined he might want to do more than just settings an property, for this purpose i posted my code - yours is clearly shorter and also answers the question!

Comment: he just asked for rows, not visible rows, of course you can use any selector you want.

Comment: Is question said a row can be removed (it's actually hided): "`$("tr:contains('3')").hide();`
Now my table has rows 2 and 4 together coloured grey. How do I retain alternate row colours despite removing a row?". To be a good answer, IT NEED to check if row is visible.

Comment: oww, i only read "removed" and thought of the rows as REMOVED, turns out, they aren´t -.-

Comment: I have tried all your suggestions and what's happening is rows 2, 4 and 6 do not change colour because they're preset to grey, but rows 1, 3 and 5 does, because they're white (no preset colours). This goes for all the codes you all provided including this one of my own: $("tr:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "lightblue");. This does not change row 2 to light blue, but $("tr:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "lightblue"); does. I don't get it.

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS then... Will be easier to help.

Comment: adding tr:nth-child(even){background-color: light blue;} to my CSS file still does not change colour to light blue on even rows. Rows 2, 4 and 6 are still grey.

Answer (score 0):

I am completing [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925764/2324107)'s answer.

You need to itterate through `tr` but change `td's` css since they are the one with the `style` tag.

```
$('tr:visible').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('td').css('background-color', i%2 ? 'red':'grey');
})
```

Hope it work.

Comment: What the code above does is make the table look like a chess board, with alternating cells of red and grey, on all the rows. I think we're getting close though. It must be my php code.

Comment: tr:visible works better, except it only changes the colour on white rows. The hard coded (212,212,212) rows remain grey.

Comment: I am dumb, didn't read the PHP carefully. Edited my answer, NOW it should work!

Comment: That works! How do I code it so that I only want row 2 to be coloured red for example?

Comment: Never mind! I modified tr:visible to tr:nth-child(2). Works perfectly! Thank you!!!